# Django: Use logging inside settings.py

Tags: python, django, logging

I successfully set up Django logging, but I find myself in need to log some information inside `settings.py`. Is that possible?

Currently, the settings only come into effect after the entire file is parsed, which I believe is expected. Is there a way to force the set up of loggers right after specifying them? Otherwise, are there any alternatives that people recommend?

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

# The below does not work because the setup declared above is not yet in effect

logger = logging.getLogger('main')
logger.info("Works?")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, but will accept other answers that might be more complete

Adding the following, will load the LOGGING as required. Not sure what are the side effects.

```
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```